# Which data structure to use for storing the XML parsed values

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I want to know a data structure for storing tags and values of My XML so that I can retrieve values from that in code easily and I don't have to parse the xml multiple times:

```
XML structure:

<suite>
    <loop>  
        <test>
            <!-- comment1 -->
            <step>
                <action>CONNECT</action>
                <request>sys</request>
            </step>
            <!-- comment2 -->
            <step>
                <action>abc</action>                        
                <request>request</request>
                <expectedResponse>enable</expectedResponse>
                <validator>contains</validator>
            </step>
        </test>
    </loop>
</suite>
```

I want to store the values at a single place using data structure, Can someone suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to store the values at a single place using data structure, Can
>   someone suggest something?

A class **is** a data structure, so just make one.

Pick any of the java xml serialization libraries, there are plenty. This will allow you to parse the xml, generate the classes, deserialize it back to xml should there be a need.

If this feels like an overkill, you can manually parse the xml and set the values in your custom class. In your case, I would just use a library for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a marshall/unmarshall library.

Start creating a java class that match your xml document. To do it, I recomend you to use JAXB-2 plugin. It's a maven plugin that generate and Java Class from a xsd schema. You must to have the schema that your xml objects follow. You just need to provide this xsd schema to the plugin and it creates you the Java class. If you don't have the schema (you should) you must Y with the fields necessary to store the values of your xml.

Once you have a Java class, just use a marshalling/unmarshalling library to extract the data from the xml. One of the most used is JAXB.

You can follow the documentation to unmarshall a xml at the oficial documentation https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_3_1-Unmarshalling-and-Using-the-Data.html#Unmarshalling